# Object detection From videos in openCV (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType')

Tags: opencv

I am using python 3.5 in Ubuntu 16.04 
https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/
used this link to download opencv3

```
File "<ipython-input-12-e1defa92c813>", line 1, in <module>
  runfile('/home/abhishek/models/research/object_detection/Video_detection.py', wdir='/home/abhishek/models/research/object_detection')

File "/home/abhishek/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
  execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/abhishek/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
  exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/home/abhishek/models/research/object_detection/Video_detection.py", line 139, in <module>
  feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

File "/home/abhishek/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
  run_metadata_ptr)

File "/home/abhishek/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1093, in _run
  np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)

File "/home/abhishek/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

> ## Python Programming Video Detection Tutorial #2

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
sys.path.append(sys.executable)


# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

# In[3]:

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# # Model preparation 

# ## Variables
# 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# 
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# In[4]:

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90
print(12)

# ## Download Model

# In[5]:

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())

print(13)

# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

# In[6]:

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

print(14)
# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

# In[7]:

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)
print(15)

# ## Helper code

# In[8]:

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# # Detection

# In[9]:

# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)


# In[10]:

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      ret, image_np = cap.read()

      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800,600)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
>
```

Please help me to proceed.I have already added my code which mostly copied from https://pythonprogramming.net/video-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

Comment: Did you debug the code? `NoneType` is probably something that you have manually entered or what a function that you've called has returned. I also didn't find a single line in the tutorial's code that handles this scenario, which indicates a bug.

Comment: Error in line 139 i.e. feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

Comment: @rbaleksandar I thought issue is related to input (may be my webcam is not working) but I tried running code with using .mp4 file.(Edited question with my code)

Comment: So it doesn't work with a file either?

Comment: you never check if cap isOpen or if ret is true (from cap.read()), test those two if they are true

Comment: Yeah, so whenever `read()` is called it returns a `NoneType` as the 
 [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1) states (it's for C++ but NULL pointer means that the Python version of the API returns `NoneType`).

Comment: @rbaleksandar it doesnt work with a file.@api55 tried 'print(ret)' it is false for both case (using file or with webcam).** If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.**It means no frame is grabbed.So issue is related to input

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Firstly crosscheck if your opencv has been correctly installed.
and before you take the source for object detection from your webcam try it with stock photos and check if it works.

Later upgrade your opencv to opencv3.

```
conda install opencv3
```

If problem still persists then check your webcam for input issuses.
Nonetype is only returned when no frames are being captured by your webcam.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, file does'nt not exist when it is picture, maybe could not transform in picture when come from video or cam. check your input